# Why does my speaker make a high noise if I remove my headphones and microphone?

Tags: sound

In my laptop after removing  headphone and microphone there is a very high noise from built-in speakers. From the first time onwards. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The noise happens after removing both headphones and external microphone, right?

Does your laptop have a built-in microphone? If so, the noise can be audio feedback from the built-in speakers into the built-in microphone.

If this is the case, try lowering the built-in microphone volume.